# Magento controller: indexAction works but all other Actions return 404

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have a custom module with a controller with few actions. Eg: testAction, indexAction and so on.

I am able to access indexAction using

www.example.com/module/controller/

or

www.example.com/module/controller/index

but all other actions Eg.(www.example.com/module/controller/test) return 404 Page not found.

**Interestingly**, everything works (I can access all actions) without altering the code when I change the Magento database (I have two databases, it works with test but fails with live).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your theme layout xml

```
<module_controller_action translate="label">
   <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="name" template="path/to/form.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</module_controller_action>
```

and

```
 public function testAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
 }
```